# Get the default IMAP store in Outlook

Tags: outlook-2007, outlook-redemption

When you set up a new IMAP email account in Outlook it creates a store with the same name as your email account. This is an IMAP store and is used to store incoming emails as the "Personal Files" store isn't compatible with IMAP.

If you programmatically look up the default store for the user it comes up with "Personal Folders". How then do you figure out what the default IMAP store is?

You can't simply look for a store with the same name as the email account because Outlook allows the user to rename their store.

If I need to bypass the object model and use a MAPI property that is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RDOStore.StoreKind property.

Edit: In combination with the above you can use the RDOStore.StoreAccount property to determine that a particular store type belongs to a particular user.

Comment: Right, but RDOSession.Stores gives me back all stores. If I have two IMAP email accounts set up each with their own IMAP store then looping through that will give me two stores with type of IMAP.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem - so you need to find which IMAP store corresponds to a particular SMTP address?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I have two SMTP accounts setup in Outlook. Each one has its own IMAP store. Getting the default store returns "Personal Folders" when using IMAP so I have to somehow determine which IMAP store to use for the current user.

Comment: Have you tried to use RDOStore.StoreAccount (returns RDOAccount property) to figure out which account a store corresponds to?

Comment: It appears that `StoreAccount` is the property that I've been looking for. Thanks again Dmitry.